# How to initialize a cookie with changing argument

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a code that needs to run a count-down timer, the counter needs to count down 15 min per user even if he\she leaves the page.
this is the cookie initialize line:

```
document.cookie = "name=timerCookie; timeLeft=" + initialTime + "; expires=" + expires;
```

and this is how I update the cookie:

```
document.cookie = "name=timerCookie; timeLeft=" + timeLeft + "; expires=" + expires;
```

when I try to read the cookie I get "name=timerCookie"

am I setting the cookie correctly?
can I use cookie this way?

EDIT****:
apparently, cookie can contain only 1 segment(aka timeLeft) by removing the name value the issue was solved.

Comment: Personally I would set the cookie only once with the time at which the timer starts. When the user comes back, you only need to check whether the timer is still active (and display the remaining time) or not.

Comment: Can you say what the purpose of this timer is? For instance, does the server need to know when the timer expires even if the user closes the browser immediately after receiving the cookie, or does it only matter when the browser sends some future request such as loading a different page on the site?

Comment: @customcommander I need the timer to countdown time within the site (including subdirectories) when the user closes the page the time is saved, and when he reopens it the countdown will continue from the last position.  in addition, I need the timer to refresh every 24 hours(aka cookie expires 24 hours after the initial cookie creation). The wierd part is the cookie seems to be initialized with only 1 section and not 3 as I intended

Comment: @TomAbarba you don’t need to store the time left as you can (and perhaps should) recompute it on demand: `now - timerStartDate`. When the cookie isn’t present (i.e first time on the page or the cookie has expired) you know you need to setup a new timer.

Comment: @customcommander, thanks, but I didn't understand what you wrote. Let's take 2 situations - first, a user logged in at 12:00 and closed the session at 12:05. when he logs back in at 13:00 timer needs to show initial time - 5 minutes. the second user logged in at 12:00 spent 10 min in the site, closed it and returned at 13:00 while both now - startTimerDate gives the same result. user 1 need time to show initialTime - 5 minutes and user2 needs the time to show initialTime - 10. Does your solution cover this? if so please help me understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I came up with this solution while I was offline and before I learned what your use case actually is.
I was thinking it would be better to use localStorage since MDN says:
 "Cookies were once used for general client-side storage. While this was
 legitimate when they were the only way to store data on the client, it
 is recommended nowadays to prefer modern storage APIs."

Since your server needs to know about the user's "time remaining", you probably want cookies after all (unless you can just have the browser update the server at  [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) time), but maybe you can adapt this idea to your purpose.

I was also thinking that "even if he/she leaves the page" meant that the timer should keep ticking while they're away -- but this part should be relatively easy to fix.

I'm including this as HTML (to copy/paste) because SO snippets are sandboxed and won't run code that uses localStorage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>
  <p id="display">__:__</p>
<script>

  let expires = localStorage.getItem("expires"); // Gets the stored expiration time
  const display = document.querySelector("#display"); // Identifies our HTML element
  // Makes a helper function to treat dates as accumulated seconds
  const getSecondsSinceEpoch = ((date) => Math.floor(date.getTime()/1000));

  // Sets the expiration time if countdown is not already running
  if(!expires){
    expires = getSecondsSinceEpoch(new Date()) + (60 * 15); // 15 minutes from now
    localStorage.setItem("expires", expires);
  }

  // Calculates how long until expiration
  let pageLoadedAt = getSecondsSinceEpoch(new Date());
  let secondsRemaining = parseInt(expires) - pageLoadedAt; 

  // Starts the countdown (which repeats once per second)
  setInterval(countdown, 1000);

  function countdown(){
    // When time expires, stops counting and clears storage for the user's next visit
    if(secondsRemaining === 0){
      clearInterval();
      localStorage.clear(); // You don't want this here -- it resets the clock
    }
    else{
      // Until time expires, updates the display with reduced time each second
      display.textContent = formatTime(--secondsRemaining);
    }
  }

  function formatTime(time){
    let mins = Math.floor(time/60).toString();
    let secs = Math.floor(time%60).toString();
    secs = secs.length == 2 ? secs : "0" + secs; // Ensures two-digit seconds
    return `${mins}:${secs}`
  }

</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!

Comment: Actually, it looks like I gave you a version that doesn't run properly. But I've been up for 24 hours of the last 26, so I'll try to tweak it later.

Comment: you don't need to my code is working now, all I needed to do is to know that you can't have more than one part (except expiration and path)

Comment: Oh, cool. If my answer is what helped you, you could help my reputation a little by marking it as accepted.